# Extra space above wrapper on FF/IE, not on Chrome/Opera

Tags: html, css

i got a css problem on [Awwwazing.com](http://awwwazing.com). The area below the big Awwwazing text is different on FF than on Chrome.

On FF it adds extra space above wrapper-6, making the space between the big text and the first post too much. I've read that adding display: inline-block to wrapper-6 might help and it does remove the extra spacing, but all my posts go to the left of the screen. Could someone help me to look it the same on FF and on Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried with this CSS and the website seems good both in Chrome and in Firefox:

```
#bodywrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

#wrapper-6 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Beaver, that did it! Do i need to add the margin left/right auto? Seems to work without those 2 lines also.

Comment: No, I think it's not necessary; I've seen on my PC both in Chrome and in FFox that it's working this way.